# How to document error messages using Spring Rest Doc

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, documentation, spring-restdocs

I'm using Spring rest doc along spring mvc test to generate a restful documentation. Now I'm trying to describe the possible error messages on the resource, but I cannot find anything that will help me in the spring documentation.

What I'm trying to achieve is similar to Error 4xx section of http://apidocjs.com/example/

Any thoughts ?

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-restdocs/

Comment: I know about this docs... thanks anyway...

Comment: From REST Docs' perspective, an error response isn't really any different to a successful response. Have you tried making a `MockMvc` call that produces an error response and then documenting it as you normally would?

Comment: Hi Andy, yes I did and it is working as the normal responses do. But what I'm trying to do is all the errors to be in a table. Just like in the link I've provided. I did it now actually with a new custom snippet which I call on "dummy" service when I harvest all the tested errors for the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a test that intentionally generates an error response.   And document the fields like you would with any other Spring Rest Docs test.

```
@Test
    public void errorExample() throws Exception {
        RestDocumentationResultHandler docs = document("Error Response",
                preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                responseFields(
                        fieldWithPath("status").optional().type("Integer").description("Application status field."),
                        fieldWithPath("errorMsg").type("String").description("A global description of the cause of the error")        

                )
        );


        AppConfig req = getAppConfigReq(null, null, null);

        ResultActions result = this.mockMvc.perform(  post("/SomeAPICall/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(req))
        );
        result.andExpect(status().is(401));
        result.andDo(docs);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for answer! Indeed I can document my custom errors as a normal responses, I have such integration test for all possible custom error outcome. I will have a lot of snippets to include and the info will not be concise. What I trying to achieve is they to be in a table for every resource. Here is a example what I did so far -> [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1l5QQ2pxq22OXhFNkl0bExMRWs/view)

I did it with a bit of "hacking" as mention in the comments and I wonder is there a more natural way of doing this as a lot of REST API docs have such error documentation.

Comment: I am not sure that I am following what is being asked, but it sounds like you want to create one global error snippet and display it in each of your calls?   That goes against Andy Wilkerson intentions on how to use Spring Rest Docs, but it can be done.   If that is the case then all you need to do after you have created the generic error snippet is to include it in each section.   So you would have a line like "include::{snippets}/Errors Object/response-fields.adoc[]" in each section pointing to your one generated error snippit.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want and I did it, like you've described. Indeed, it seems it is against the Spring's Rest Docs way of documenting. Thanks for your asnwers and attention.